# android AlertDialog display once

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I want to display dialog only once at installation. I am accepting value from user in currentIntervalChoice. But it is not accessible in else part. How can I do this. I have declared currentIntervalChoice globally. like this.

```
   int currentIntervalChoice;
```

this is my code:

```
   private void doFirstRun()
{
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (settings.getBoolean("isFirstRun", true))
    {
        //-------------------------------------------------------------------------
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"in 1st run true", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.prompts, null);
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        // set prompts.xml to alertdialog builder
        alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);
        final EditText userInput = (EditText) promptsView
                .findViewById(R.id.editTextDialogUserInput);

        // set dialog message
        alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("OK",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which)
            {
                 String value = userInput.getText().toString();
                 currentIntervalChoice=Integer.parseInt(value);
                toggleLogging(AppSettings.getServiceRunning(MainActivity.this),
                        AppSettings.setLoggingInterval(MainActivity.this,currentIntervalChoice));
                dialog.dismiss();
                // return;  
            }
              });
        // create alert dialog
        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        // show it
        alertDialog.show();
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("isFirstRun", false);
        editor.commit();
    }
    else
    {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"in 1st run false", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();       
        toggleLogging(AppSettings.getServiceRunning(MainActivity.this),
                AppSettings.setLoggingInterval(MainActivity.this,currentIntervalChoice));
    }
}
```

I am calling doFirstRun() in onCreate() of my Activity.

ThankYou

Comment: It's not clear where is the problem; if you want to save that value use `SharedPreferences` or a private variable in the activity

Comment: I hava used shared preferences. Is there any mistake

Comment: Where have you passed your current interval in the else part ?

Comment: Pass your interval value in else part `toggleLogging(AppSettings.getServiceRunning(MainActivity.this),                AppSettings.setLoggingInterval(MainActivity.this,currentIntervalChoice));`

Comment: Yup I am using it there only. But it is not taking the value from onClick() of alertDialog

Comment: What you doing is right and it should work but not getting your actual issue. Private int currentIntervalChoice; try this

Comment: Any crashes ? if so post teh stacktrace

Comment: You are not making the boolean false after first run thats why its running if part only,have a look at my edit post

Answer (score 0):

i used this

```
boolean disclaimer = getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, 0).getBoolean(DISCLAIMER, false);
                if(!disclaimer)
                    {
                    startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this,DisclaimerActivity.class));
                    }else{                  
                        startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this,MainActivity.class));
                    }
```

and in disclaimer activity updated the pref value

```
public void onAccept(View v) {
    Editor edit = getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, 0).edit();
    edit.putBoolean(DISCLAIMER, true);
    edit.commit();
```

Comment: Its working properly.But the problem is that I am unable to access the value of currentIntervalChoice in else part. toggleLogging(context,int) starts my service at interval=currentIntervalChoice

Answer (score 0):

Use SQLite. Maybe next time need to show Dialog.